# Backup MySQL Database using C#

Tags: c#, mysql

Is it possible to periodically backup my MySQL Database from my application (C#). I will create the application as a Windows Service or Console app and schedule using Windows Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an awesome Library available to Backup and Restore MySQL database in C#.

The code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/MySqlBackupNET/MySqlBackup.Net) and can also be added as a [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlBackup.NET/) package as well.

Use the below code to do a backup.

```
string connstr = "server=localhost;user=root;pwd=mypass;database=mydb;sslmode=none;convertdatetime=true;";
string backupfile = "C:\\backup.sql";

using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connstr))
{
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
    {
        using (MySqlBackup mb = new MySqlBackup(cmd))
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Connection = conn;

            mb.ExportToFile(backupfile);

            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Backup will be saved in C:\backup.sql

Comment: That's a nice way to accomplish the task.